# Codeigniter error with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I am using sql server database drivers in codeigniter and I am executing the following query:

```
 select A.inst_name,Substring((Select ',' + cast(B.program_id as varchar(15))   
                               From    k12_dms_inst_programs B
                               Where B.inst_id=A.id For XML Path('')),2,8000) As EmployeeList
 From k12_dms_institution_master A
 Group by A.inst_name,A.id
```

which is working absolutely fine in **SSMS**.

But when I am trying to execute the same query using Codeigniter I am getting the following error:--

Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using **DB-Library** (such as ISQL) or **ODBC version 3.7 or earlier**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some solutions on php.net

1. MSSQLNewbie 19-Sep-2011 06:34

   ```
   In /etc/freetds/freetds.conf add these two lines (last two):
   [global]
   ;tds version = 4.2
   tds version = 8.0  
   client charset = UTF-8

   You can edit "charset" in php.ini too (but you don't need if you did it previously in freetds.conf):  
   ; Specify client character set.. 
   ; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.comf is used 
   ; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS mssql.charset = "UTF-8"

   Use nchar/nvarchar/ntext column types if you need unicode support.
   ```
2. dann dot farquhar at iteams dot org 24-Sep-2009 11:45

   ```
   I found that changing the version in /etc/freetds.conf from 4.2 to 8.0
   fixes this problem without having to make any changes to the SELECT
   statement
   ```
3. huberkev11 at hotmail dot com 12-May-2006 01:47

   ```
   This is because you are using column types of like ntext instead of
   text.  There are 2 solutions.

   1  Change all ntext column types to text or
   2  Your query must look like: SELECT CAST(field1 AS TEXT) AS field1 FROM table
   ```

Hope they will help.

Comment: @user1163513 tell us which of them did help you!